# Date range control for multiple data sources

Tags: date, parameters, datepicker, range, looker-studio

Im looking for a way to use one date range control for multiple data sources. Is it possible, either via parameter or via date picker, many thanks!

Ive tried so far couple of things, but none worked. Much help would be apprecited

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.